# Not able to animate with ConstraintSet : plop.xml plop_alt.xml

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I am new to ConstraintLayout and I was trying to make a simple animation:

One button, one text, when I click on button, the text go from top of screen to bot of screen. And if you click again same thing but inverse. Please do not care of refactoring possibilities, I am just trying to do something that works. No animation seems to work.

My XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/merde">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/plop_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my alt XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/merde">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/textview"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/plop_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my controllers:

```
public class Plop extends Controller {

    @BindView(R.id.plop_button)
    AppCompatButton button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plop, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this , view);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
                    ConstraintLayout controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.plop,null);
                    ConstraintSet constraintSetAlt = new ConstraintSet();

                    transition.setDuration(1000);

                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout, transition);

                    ConstraintLayout c1 = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.plop_alt,null);
                    constraintSetAlt.clone(c1);
                    constraintSetAlt.applyTo(controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {

    }

    @Override
    public void loadData() {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateView() {

    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

EDIT : The issue above is fixed thanks to plaskoff.

I'am trying now to do that in an activity :

In my onCreated :

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.controllers_loading_root);
    ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
    ConstraintLayout controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.controllers_loading_root_constraint_layout);
    ConstraintSet constraintSetAlt = new ConstraintSet();
    transition.setDuration(1000);TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout, transition);
    ConstraintLayout c1 = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.controllers_loading_root_alt,null);
    constraintSetAlt.clone(c1);
    constraintSetAlt.applyTo(controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout);
    ...
}
```

My activity appear in final state with no animation done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong `ConstraintLayout` instance to animate:

```
ConstraintLayout controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.plop,null)
```

You are inflating a new `ConstraintLayout` object which is not the same one as the currently displayed. So what you should do is replace the above line with:

```
ConstraintLayout controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.merde);
```

As a side note, you don't have to instantiate a new `ConstraintLayout` object to clone the constraints. You can use `void clone (Context context, int constraintLayoutId)` to clone them from a layout file.

**EDIT to answer the follow-up question:**

If you want to start the animation as soon as the activity is shown you can move the code for the animation to `onWindowFocusChanged()` method in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.controllers_loading_root);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        ConstraintLayout controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.controllers_loading_root_constraint_layout);
        ConstraintSet constraintSetAlt = new ConstraintSet();
        transition.setDuration(1000);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout, transition);
        ConstraintLayout c1 = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.controllers_loading_root_alt,null);
        constraintSetAlt.clone(c1);
        constraintSetAlt.applyTo(controllersLoadingRootConstaintLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey thanks I will try out this one tomorrow and keep you updated.

Comment: Working all good, do you know how to animate an activity at start of this one with this things ? I'am now thanks yo you able to animate fragment. But activity seems still broke.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. What's wrong with the activity?

Comment: I will edit my question (Adding this one at then end to give you code)

Comment: Updated my answer, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Still not enough rep for a comment, so as an answer (hmpf):
First of all, your TextView in the alt layout doesn't have an ID, not sure if that's part of the problem, just wanted to point it out.
Second of all, you put the cloning stuff in the onClick. You should put that in the onCreateView (for example) as stated in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet) and just use the applyTo in the onClick.

Comment: First : It does actually, but he is at end of TextView.

Second : Okey, i will do that thanks.